# How to create and set variables as classes from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, class, loops, tuples

I am trying to figure out how to create variables from a list of tuple and assign them to a class.

I have data organized like this

```
 Name  Age  Status
 John  30   Employed
```

That I have created a list of tuple like this

```
 employeelist = [(John, 30, Employed), (Steve, 25, Part-Time)]
```

And a class set up like this

```
class Employee():
ecount = 0
elist = []

def __init__(self, name, age, emp_status):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.emp_status = emp_status
    self.lookup = {}
    Employee.ecount = Employee.ecount+1
    Employee.elist.append(self.name)
```

Using this code I am able to turn the tuple into an instance of the class

```
 for i in range(0, len(employeelist),1):
    sublist = [str(n) for n in employeelist[i]]
    Employee(sublist[0], sublist[1], sublist[2])
```

But I am not able to access them. Is there a way to think about setting up the for loop to create a variable from sublist[0] and then create a class out of it (e.g. sublist[0] = Employee(sublist[0], sublist[1], sublist[2]))?

Answer (score 4):

You just need

```
employees = [Employee(*v) for v in employee_list]
```

Note that `employees` and `Employee.elist` are essentially the same once
each `Employee` object has been created.

Comment: Way more pythonic:) I think this is a dumb question and shows my noobness, but how can I get John's Age through the class once I have the objects created?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean: which object `e` in the list has `e.name == "John"`? Without some index, you just need to walk through it: `johns_age =   [e.age for e in employees if e.name == "John"][0]`.

Comment: Thanks again. I have looked into indexing and am thoroughly confused on how to do it. Can you link me to something you think would be helpful for a beginner?

Comment: A `dict` can be a simple index: `d = {"John": Employee("John", 30, "Employed")}`. Here, you could access the correct `Employeed` object using `d[name]` as long as `name` was set to the correct value.

Comment: My ultimate objective is to use objects to analyze a much larger dataset, so I will need something other than setting a unique variable for each employee. Does that make sense?

Comment: Had a duh moment where I can just run a for loop on employees to get all ages. 

     for i in employees:
         print (i.age)